# What was Einstein's contribution to the Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen (EPR) paper?

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, einstein

Do we have any insight or document into theoretical development of the EPR papers both in terms of math, ideas and anything related to actual physical problem.
I know that Einstein didn't write the papers, but I couldn't find anything about how the work can be actually credited between Einstein, Podolsky and Rosen. Did Einstein contribute essential ideas or just supported the papers with his name and interest to give them prominence and take them to the attention of the scientific community?

Comment: have a look https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04648